# Странное поведение Viewport в OpenTk

Tags: c#, wpf, opentk

Суть в чем: я хочу просто нарисовать линию по всей ширине экрана, соответственно я задаю GL.Viewport(0, 0, (int)Width, (int)Height) и GL.Ortho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1), перед этим очищая матрицу вида и проекции. Но линия занимает не всю ширину окна, почему так происходит я не понимаю.

Использую GlWpfControl 4.2.3. Может кто сталкивался с таким и знает, как это решить.

```
private void Render()
{
    GL.ClearColor(Color.White);
    GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection);
    GL.LoadIdentity();
    GL.Viewport(0, 0, (int)Width, (int)Height);
    GL.Ortho(-1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1);

    GL.Color3(Color.Black);
    GL.Begin(PrimitiveType.Lines);
    GL.Vertex2(-1, -0.8);
    GL.Vertex2(1, -0.8);
    GL.End();
}
```

Comment: Как воспроизвести то, о чем вы говорите?

Comment: С чем вообще может быть связана эта проблема?